# showing topological invariance

Tags: general-topology

i am stuck in the following question:
"show that the property of a space E that every closed loop in E can be shrunk to a point in E is a  topological invariant property of E."

intuitively i am getting an idea that if E' is homeomorphic to E, the shrinking of a given path in E', can be carried out by copying, step by step, the shrinking of the corresponding path in E. but ,i am not able to prove it...

any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Do you know the correct notion of "shrink to a point" (namely homotopy) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shrinking a path $c:I\rightarrow E$ to a point is equivalent to there exists a continuous function
$H:I\times I\rightarrow E$ such that $H(0,t)=c(t), H(1,t)=x\in E$.

Thus if $f:E\rightarrow E'$ is an homeomorphism, and every path in $E$ can be shrinked to a point, consider the path $c:I\rightarrow E'$, $f^{-1}\circ c$ is a path of $E$, so there exists $H$ like above, you can define $H'=f\circ H$ which allows to shrink $c$ to a point.